# Why IntPtr cannot be used when in subsequent call

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

My program:

```
class Program {
    [DllImport("libiconvD.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr libiconv_open([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
                                          string tocode, 
                                          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
                                          string fromcode);

    [DllImport("libiconvD.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern ulong libiconv(IntPtr icd,
                             ref StringBuilder inbuf, ref ulong inbytesleft,
                             out StringBuilder outbuf, out ulong outbytesleft);

    [DllImport("libiconvD.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int libiconv_close(IntPtr icd);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var inbuf = new StringBuilder("Rule(s): Global Tag â€“ Refer to Print Rules â€“ General Requirements");
        ulong inbytes = (ulong)inbuf.Length;
        ulong outbytes = inbytes;
        StringBuilder outbuf = new StringBuilder((int)outbytes);

        IntPtr icd = libiconv_open("utf8", "windows-1252");
        var rcode1 = libiconv(icd, ref inbuf, ref inbytes, out outbuf, out outbytes);
        Debug.WriteLine(rcode1);
        var rcode2 = libiconv_close(icd);
        Debug.WriteLine(rcode2);
    }//Main()
}//Program CLASS
```

The first call of libiconv_open() works and return a pointer to icd.
When the 2nd call of libiconv() runs it gets access violation on the icd pointer.

Here is the C code being called:

```
size_t iconv (iconv_t icd,
              ICONV_CONST char* * inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft,
              char* * outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft)
{
  conv_t cd = (conv_t) icd;
  if (inbuf == NULL || *inbuf == NULL)
    return cd->lfuncs.loop_reset(icd,outbuf,outbytesleft);
  else
    return cd->lfuncs.loop_convert(icd,
                                   (const char* *)inbuf,inbytesleft,
                                   outbuf,outbytesleft);
}
```

[image]
It seems it can't access the function defined in the structure that pointer points to.  Is there something special that has to be done to a returned pointer to make usable in subsequent calls.

Thanks

Comment: Does `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` look like a valid pointer value to you? Note that hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFFFF... (all bits set) is also the two's-complement representation for a signed integer `-1`. I guess you need to read the documentation for `libiconv_open` about what values it can return in error cases, and what those error cases can/might be...

Comment: Are you certain that the routines in libiconD.DLL are compiled with cdecl calling convention?

Comment: Yes it is got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using libiconv library is unnecessary with C#.  Just use the Encoding class.

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            Encoding w1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

            string inbuf = "Rule(s): Global Tag â€“ Refer to Print Rules â€“ General Requirements";
            byte[] bytearray = utf8.GetBytes(inbuf);
            byte[] outbytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, w1252, bytearray);

            Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("  Input: {0}", inbuf));
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(" Output: {0}", utf8.GetString(outbytes)));
            Debug.WriteLine("*************************");

        }//Main()

*************************
  Input: Rule(s): Global Tag â€“ Refer to Print Rules â€“ General Requirements
 Output: Rule(s): Global Tag – Refer to Print Rules – General Requirements
*************************
```